# How do I create a tar archive that will not expand to a subfolder?

Tags: unix, tar, directory-structure, archive-tar

I don't want to create a "flat" tarball that has no internal directory structure. But I want the top-level files to be "loose" rather than mirroring the directory structure they were on originally.

Consider:

```
+ archives
|
+ data
    |
    + site
        |
        + file1.html
        |
        + subdirectory
               |
               + etc...
```

If I `cd` into `archives` and create my tar there, eg: `tar -czf archive.tgz ../data/site/*` when I extract the tarball later it will recreate `data/site/...` and then I'll have to `mv data/site/* ../some/other/dir`.

I'd like to be able to just `tar -xzf archive.tgz -C ../some/other/dir` and have eg file1.html be right there inside `../some/other/dir`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `cd`ing to `archives` and running `tar` there with a path to the tarfile contents, you should `cd` to where the contents are and specify a path to the tarfile you're creating:

```
cd data/site
tar -czf ../../archives/archive.tgz *
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the option `tar -czf archive.tgz --directory=data/site/ .` without going to the folder